# Google Contacts Authentication Using OAuth2 in Java

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I want to connect to Google Contacts API and access the contacts of any user who logins my application in Java

I am not able to find a proper documentation for this.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) helps you.

This is the documentation for using OAuth with Google Services.

Answer (score 0):

The documents are very hectic and not clear at all.

Please let me know if you can give me a clear document of tutorial of how to proceed.

Thanks